# How to include *.so file in Android-gradle application?

Tags: android, gradle

I need to do a simple thing: include .so in the project. Here's what I have now:

```
# app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.123"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22

        versionCode 7113
        versionName "7113"
    }


    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86", "x86_64"
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
            }
        }

    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'io.pristine:libjingle:8871'
}

# build.gradle
all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And I have these "so" files in **src/src/main/jniLibs**:

```
   /arm64-v8a/file1_so.so
   /armeabi-v7a/file1_so.so
   /x86/file1_so.so
   /x86_64/file1_so.so
```

However, when I launch my application I get an error which implies the application is using the "old" **so** file which already has been embedded into it before. So I'm unsure any of these files are getting compiled into the result **apk** at all.

What should I do to include them into the output apk for sure?

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: @JaredBurrows, yes, but I had fixed it before I saw it, I don't remember exactly how, but simpler.

Comment: Can you chose an answer?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes, I can chose an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I bring in my prebuilt `*.so` into my apps, just make sure your `*.so` are in the `src/main/libs` folder:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        main {
            jni {
                srcDirs = []
            }

            jniLibs {
                srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            }
        }
    }
}
```